# Can you programmatically open the "Run as different user" dialog box?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, runas

When I research this particular issue, I get countless articles on impersonation, but I don't think that's what I'm looking for. I have a C# application that opens other applications on the PC (Outlook, VNC, AD, etc). One of those apps requires users to login using their credentials, so the usual process is to [shift+right-click] the shortcut and choose "Run as different user"... A dialog box then appears asking for credentials. I'm not wanting to launch the application USING their credentials like impersonation does. I'm just wanting to launch the application as if the user had [shift+right-click]ed the shortcut so that they will be presented with the dialog box. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

call [CredUIPromptForCredentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375177(v=vs.85).aspx) then pass the result to [ProcessStartInfo](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2004/06/02/running-processes-as-a-different-user/).

Comment: [Here is the C# code to do it](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/credui.creduipromptforcredentials)